# Custom List Display Form doesn't apply to all users

Tags: 2013, custom-form, display-form

I created a custom Display Form but only system admin can see this change. I set the disp form as default disp form and checked in. What else should I do? Thank you.

Comment: following link will help you http://www.intrateam.com/gb/blogpost/sharepoint-2013-list-custom-form Is this form created using SharePoint Designer?

Comment: No I just modify the xsl link. I didn't use SP Designer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the page is published as a major version/is approved

Comment: How can I publish the home page or list?